# Is it possible to control final PDF options?

Tags: pdf

I am preparing a report on my research to be sent to my group, however, I don't want the reader to select the text and content, copy the code listings, etc.

Is there any package or options to do so?

Comment: Search for `\glyphtounicode`, cmap (a package), but without knowledge about your document code it is cumbersome to answer.

Comment: Thank you @KeksDose, the package seems to be removed from CTAN?

Comment: thanks @EricMarsden